# Calculating the day time and night time between two dates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, date, time, nsdate

I am trying to calculate, in seconds, the amount of day time and night time between two dates, given that "night time" is defined as 8:00PM through 7:59 AM, and "day time" as 8:00AM through 7:59PM. The past date that I will be comparing to the current timestamp will always be less than 24 hours than the time now.

How would I do this?

Comment: well a real dirty way of doing it ive tried is to work out the number of seconds between the dates then, loop through each second adding it to the 2nd time. then checking to see if its between the time values. Cant seem to get my head round it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This quickly becomes complicated when you start dealing with daylight savings time and such, so you really need to work with your current calendar and use the calendar/date functions for calculating time differences.

For instance, if the clock moves forward 1 hour at 3:00 AM, you should have 11 hours of "night" (instead of 12) by your definition on the day of the time change.

I have not thoroughly tested this code, but it should be pretty close:

```
// 8:00:00 AM in seconds
static const NSTimeInterval daytimeStart = 28800;
// 8:00:00 PM in seconds
static const NSTimeInterval daytimeStop  = 72000;

// Convert date to a "time" which is the number of seconds since midnight, NOT considering time changes
- (NSTimeInterval)getTimeForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit | 
                                                    NSMinuteCalendarUnit | 
                                                    NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                         fromDate:date];
    NSTimeInterval time = dateComps.hour * 3600 + dateComps.minute * 60 + dateComps.second;
    return time;
}

// Set the time to the specified hour and minutes/seconds to 0
- (NSDate *)dateBySettingTimeToBeginningOfHour:(NSUInteger)hour ofDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit |
                                   NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                                   NSDayCalendarUnit |
                                   NSHourCalendarUnit | 
                                   NSMinuteCalendarUnit | 
                                   NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                         fromDate:date];
    [dateComps setHour:hour];
    [dateComps setMinute:0];
    [dateComps setSecond:0];
    NSDate *newDate = [cal dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    return newDate;
}

// Add one day to the current date
- (NSDate *)dateByAddingOneDayToDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit |
                                   NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                                   NSDayCalendarUnit |
                                   NSHourCalendarUnit | 
                                   NSMinuteCalendarUnit | 
                                   NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                         fromDate:date];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComps day] + 1];
    NSDate *newDate = [cal dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    return newDate;
}

// Check to see if it is daytime
- (BOOL)isDayForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSTimeInterval time = [self getTimeForDate:date];
    if (time >= daytimeStart) {
        if (time < daytimeStop) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    // Default
    return NO;
}

// Check to see if it is night
- (BOOL)isNightForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    return ![self isDayForDate:date];
}

// When do we transition from day to night or night to day next?
- (NSDate *)dateForNextTransitionForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSTimeInterval time = [self getTimeForDate:date];
    if (time < daytimeStart) {
        return [self dateBySettingTimeToBeginningOfHour:8 ofDate:date];
    }

    if (time < daytimeStop) {
        return [self dateBySettingTimeToBeginningOfHour:20 ofDate:date];
    }

    // Tomorrow morning
    NSDate *newDate = [self dateByAddingOneDayToDate:date];
    newDate = [self dateBySettingTimeToBeginningOfHour:8 ofDate:newDate];
    return newDate;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)nightTimeFromDate:(NSDate *)startingDate toDate:(NSDate *)laterDate {
    if ([startingDate compare:laterDate] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        return 0;
    }

    NSTimeInterval nightTime    = 0;
    NSDate *now                 = laterDate;
    NSDate *transitionDate      = startingDate;
    NSDate *loopDate            = startingDate;
    BOOL isNight                = [self isNightForDate:startingDate];

    do {
        transitionDate = [self dateForNextTransitionForDate:transitionDate];
        if ([transitionDate compare:now] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            transitionDate = now;
        }

        if (isNight) {
            nightTime = nightTime + [transitionDate timeIntervalSinceDate:loopDate];
        }

        loopDate = transitionDate;
        isNight = !isNight;
    } while ([transitionDate compare:now] != NSOrderedSame);

    return nightTime;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)dayTimeFromDate:(NSDate *)startingDate toDate:(NSDate *)laterDate {
    if ([startingDate compare:laterDate] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        return 0;
    }

    NSTimeInterval diff = [laterDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startingDate];
    diff = diff - [self nightTimeFromDate:startingDate toDate:laterDate];
    return diff;
}

// Example usage:
NSDate *now  = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-82800 sinceDate:now];

NSLog(@"%f", [self nightTimeFromDate:date toDate:now]);
NSLog(@"%f", [self dayTimeFromDate:date toDate:now]);

// Results are 43200.000000 and 39600.000000 right now in the middle of the day.
```

Comment: wow, thanks very much. will take a look. I actually got it working by appending each second onto the date in a loop until it reaches the current date, getting the date component hour and checking if it was between 8 and 20. - a very dirty solution.

Comment: You're welcome!  I just made a small change (added isNight into the loop in nightTimeFromDate) to make it more efficient.

Comment: thanks very much. get the same result as my loop method, but your solution is miles faster. I dont really understand the logic behind it though.

Comment: Well, mine would be even faster if it didn't have to account for daylight savings time and such.  :)  Basically what I do is take the starting date/time and look forward to see when we will change from day to night (or vice versa depending on when we start).  I then calculate the time difference between the two and start a running total of night time (if it started as night).  Then I do the same thing, looking forward from the second time (so keep moving forward 12 hours at a time) until I reach the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Daytime hours = ((# of days between today and last day) * 12) + (# of daytime hours today) + (# of daytime hours on last day)

Nighttime hours = ((# of days between today and last day) * 12) + (# of nighttime hours today) + (# of nighttime hours on last day)

**EDIT**

```
int dthours = 0, nthours = 0;

dthours += ternary with a calculation of 24 - starthour logic for daytime
nthours += ternary with a calculation of 24 - starthour logic for nighttime
dthours += ternary with a calculation of endhour logic for daytime
nthours += ternary with a calculation of endhour logic for nighttime
```

logic for tomorrow's nighttime hours looks something like:

```
nthours += (endhour - 4 > 0) ? ((endhour - 16 > 0) ? endhour - 12 : 4) : endhour;
```

Comment: there is no days between last day and today, will always be less than 24 hours.

Comment: realized you meant in seconds... replace the 24 with 86400, 16 with 57600, 4 with 14400, and starthour with startsecond etc. to calculate seconds.